# How to iterate through postman JSON response and store it to global variable based on if else condition is met?

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

I have a array object in json response in which i want to loop through isRetail parameter and set the id to global variable if the condition is met.
Sample JSON response:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 95,                
                "isRetail": true
            },
            {
                "id": 118,               
                "isRetail": false
            }
        ],
        "pagination": {
            "pageNumber": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "totalCount": 2,
            "totalPages": 1,
            "isFirst": true,
            "isLast": true,
            "totalCountOnPage": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my current test code that doesn't work but more or less what I'm working towards.

```
res=pm.response.json()
let users_len = res.data.users.length
for(let i= 0; i <= users_len; i++){
     is_retail = res.data.users[i].isRetail;
    if(is_retail == "true"){
        
        pm.globals.set("UserId",res.data.users[i].id);
    }else if (is_retail == "false"){
        
pm.globals.set("orgUserId",res.data.users[i].id);
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error while executing the script.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isRetail')
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Define: "it doesn't work". Are you seeing errors? Are you not getting the right output? What _is_ the correct output? You should add that information to your question.

Comment: @Andy, My bad. Updated the question with the error i am facing.

Comment: Have you debug the code? What is the output if you console log res variable?

Comment: `i <= users_len;` array indexes start at zero so your last array index is `length-1`, use `<` instead. Your loop is going outside the array bounds so your last iteration is going to give you an undefined value for `users[i]`

Comment: @CodeThing, Below is the output of res varibale. 
{status: 200, data: {…}}
status: 200
data: {…}
users: [1]
0: {…}
id: 197880
isRetail: true
pagination: {…}
pageNumber: 1
pageSize: 25
totalCount: 1
totalPages: 1
isFirst: true
isLast: true
totalCountOnPage: 1

Comment: Also the condition should be __is_retail === true__ instead of __is_retail == "true"__

Comment: @PatrickEvans, Thanks. Issue resolved. I am able to loop through as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = pm.response.json();
let users_len = res.data.users.length;

for (let i = 0; i < users_len; i++) {
  let is_retail = res.data.users[i].isRetail;
  if (is_retail === true) { // Comparing with boolean true, not the string "true"
    pm.globals.set("UserId", res.data.users[i].id);
  } else if (is_retail === false) { // Comparing with boolean false, not the string "false"
    pm.globals.set("orgUserId", res.data.users[i].id);
  }
}
```

Here are the changes made to the code:

- In the for loop, the condition i <= users_len has been changed to i < users_len. This ensures that the loop iterates only up to the last index of the users array.
- The variable is_retail is declared with the let keyword to avoid any scope-related issues.
- The conditions in the if statements now compare is_retail with the boolean values true and false, respectively, instead of comparing with the strings "true" and "false". This aligns with the JSON structure where isRetail is a boolean value.

By making these modifications, the code should now correctly access the isRetail property and set the corresponding global variables based on the boolean values.